# Drop Down menu disables sticky navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

I have a navigation menu that it at the top of a single page scrolling site.  It uses the "sticky" jquery plugin to keep it visible when the page scrolls.  It works perfectly until I add the nested unordered list for the drop down menu.
Here is the site with the drop down:

http://creativelaunch.net/clients/mediafactory/option-b/

This is the code for the sticky plugin:

```
    (function($) {
       var defaults = {
           topSpacing: 0,
           bottomSpacing: 0,
           className: 'is-sticky',
           wrapperClassName: 'sticky-wrapper',
           center: false,
           getWidthFrom: ''
     },

    $window = $(window),
    $document = $(document),
    sticked = [],
    windowHeight = $window.height(),
    scroller = function() {
      var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
        documentHeight = $document.height(),
        dwh = documentHeight - windowHeight,
        extra = (scrollTop > dwh) ? dwh - scrollTop : 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < sticked.length; i++) {
        var s = sticked[i],
          elementTop = s.stickyWrapper.offset().top,
          etse = elementTop - s.topSpacing - extra;

        //update height in case of dynamic content
        s.stickyWrapper.css('height', s.stickyElement.outerHeight());

        if (scrollTop <= etse) {
          if (s.currentTop !== null) {
            s.stickyElement
              .css('position', '')
              .css('top', '');
            s.stickyElement.parent().removeClass(s.className);
            s.currentTop = null;
          }
        }
        else {
          var newTop = documentHeight - s.stickyElement.outerHeight()
            - s.topSpacing - s.bottomSpacing - scrollTop - extra;
          if (newTop < 0) {
            newTop = newTop + s.topSpacing;
          } else {
            newTop = s.topSpacing;
          }
          if (s.currentTop != newTop) {
            s.stickyElement
              .css('position', 'fixed')
              .css('top', newTop);

            if (typeof s.getWidthFrom !== 'undefined') {
              s.stickyElement.css('width', $(s.getWidthFrom).width());
            }

            s.stickyElement.parent().addClass(s.className);
            s.currentTop = newTop;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    resizer = function() {
      windowHeight = $window.height();
    },
    methods = {
      init: function(options) {
        var o = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
          var stickyElement = $(this);

          var stickyId = stickyElement.attr('id');
          var wrapper = $('<div></div>')
            .attr('id', stickyId + '-sticky-wrapper')
            .addClass(o.wrapperClassName);
          stickyElement.wrapAll(wrapper);

          if (o.center) {
            stickyElement.parent().css({width:stickyElement.outerWidth(),marginLeft:"auto",marginRight:"auto"});
          }

          if (stickyElement.css("float") == "right") {
            stickyElement.css({"float":"none"}).parent().css({"float":"right"});
          }

          var stickyWrapper = stickyElement.parent();
          stickyWrapper.css('height', stickyElement.outerHeight());
          sticked.push({
            topSpacing: o.topSpacing,
            bottomSpacing: o.bottomSpacing,
            stickyElement: stickyElement,
            currentTop: null,
            stickyWrapper: stickyWrapper,
            className: o.className,
            getWidthFrom: o.getWidthFrom
          });
        });
      },
      update: scroller
    };

  // should be more efficient than using $window.scroll(scroller) and $window.resize(resizer):
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scroller, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizer, false);
  } else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onscroll', scroller);
    window.attachEvent('onresize', resizer);
  }

  $.fn.sticky = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.sticky');
    }
  };
  $(function() {
    setTimeout(scroller, 0);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the code for the drop down menu:

```
<!--HEADER START-->
            <nav class="header home-section clearfix">
                    <div class="for-sticky">
                        <div class="container nav-box">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <a href="index.html">
                                    <img class="logo1" alt="Media Factory" src="images/mf-logo-white-main.png">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-box hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                <ul class="navigation">
                                    <li class="current"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#about">About Us</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">The Factory</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Meet The Team</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Who We Serve</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                                    <li><a href="#works">Our Work</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Printing</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Signs, Banners +</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Mailing</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Vehicle Graphics</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Promotional Items</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a class="external" href="#">Blog</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#resources">Resources</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Upload Files</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Estimate Request</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Place An Order</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">File Specs</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Mailing Specs</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a class="external" href="#">Our Store</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div><!--/.menu-box-->
                            <div class="box-mobile hidden-lg hidden-md">
                                <div class="menu-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                                    <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="nav-collapse mobile-menu hidden-lg hidden-md"></ul>
                            </div><!--/.box-mobile-->
                        </div><!--/.container-->
                    </div><!--/.for-sticky-->
            </nav><!--/.header-->
            <!--HEADER END-->
```

Finally, here the CSS code for the drop down.  It uses the same style as the parent menu.  If I remove the drop down and its CSS code, the sticky starts working again.

```
/*-----------------------------HEADER SECTION-----------------------------------*/
.home-section.header {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:999;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    max-width: 20%;
}
.menu-box {
    float: right;
    max-width: 80%;
    text-align: right;
}

/*----------------------------------------------*/
.navigation {
    display: block;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navigation li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
    padding: 15px 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navigation li a:hover{color:#cc227b;}

.navigation li ul {
  display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    left: 10%;
}

.navigation li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.navigation .current a{color:#cc227b;}

.for-sticky {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:9999;
    transition: ease .3s;
    -webkit-transition: ease .3s;
    -moz-transition: ease .3s;
    -o-transition: ease .3s;
    -ms-transition: ease .3s;
}

.is-sticky .for-sticky {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I would use a fixed header without the sticky stuff: https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/3ne2tbgq/

Comment: Thanks!! That fixed it.